# How can I count the nominal data from multiple columns

Tags: pandas, count, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, addition

Let's say I have a data that looks like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'a':["Yes","No", "Yes"], 
'b':["Yes","No", "No"], 
'c':["Yes","Yes", "Yes"], 
'd':["No","Yes", "No"], 
'e':["Yes","No", "Yes"]})
```

I want to count each **`Yes`** from my dataframe and add as new column.
The result would look like below.

|  | a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | Yes | 4 |
| 1 | No | No | Yes | Yes | No | 2 |
| 2 | Yes | No | Yes | No | Yes | 3 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
df['f'] = df.eq('Yes').sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      a   b   c   d   e  f
0   Yes Yes Yes  No Yes  4
1    No  No Yes Yes  No  2
2   Yes  No Yes  No Yes  3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Didn't know eq() exists. I only thought about "df.loc" but looks like I can use eq() in this case!

Comment: You're welcome. Eq() is equivalent to ==, which could be also used in your case: (df == 'Yes').sum(axis=1)